# Inline row editing's onSuccess event is not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid with inline row editing and I want to let the user an indication if a row updating is succeed or not.

The problem is that the onSuccess event is not firing after row editing update, actually none of the action events are fired.

Note: i'm using JSON server data only, no local data.

There is a good HTTP post to the server.

This is my code:

```
    colNames:['Actions',...],
                    colModel:[
                        {name:'act',index:'act',width:55,align:'center',sortable:false,formatter:'actions',
                         formatoptions:{
                             keys: true,
                             onEdit:function(rowid) {
                             },
                             onSuccess:function(jqXHR) {
                                 alert('The update succeed!');
                             },
                             onError:function(rowid, jqXHR, textStatus) {
 alert('There was some problem, check the row!');
                             },
                             afterSave:function(rowid) {

                             },
                             afterRestore:function(rowid) {

                             }
                         }}
```

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: got any javascript error in firebug or developer tools?

Comment: no, the data is http posted ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, the problem was old jqGrid version(3.8) which I used.

Use jqGrid 4.3.0 and later for it to work properly and also make sure your jQuery version is up-to-date.

Yair